# Adding different rows in SQL based on column value as new row and new column value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm entirely willing to admit that I am going about this incorrectly, but here's the situation. I was given a table like this:

```
qtr    cust_type      cust_cnt           

QTR1   new_cust       100
QTR1   return_cust    50 
QTR2   new_cust       150  
QTR2   return_cust    75
```

and I am trying to create a new cust_type row for each qtr that shows the combined amounts of the other cust_types, like this as an end result:

```
qtr    cust_type      cust_cnt           

QTR1   new_cust       100
QTR1   return_cust    60 
QTR1   total_cust     160
QTR2   new_cust       150  
QTR2   return_cust    75
QTR2   total_cust     225
```

Why on earth would I do this? The reason is not great- Tableau is very picky about how information is input in order to form specific graph types.

Is there some SQL syntax that can accomplish the second graph? I cannot seem to figure one out. I'm also very new to SQL :D

Comment: I think Tableau should be able to add those summary rows. Either way the `union` approach should be good too.

Comment: Why the `50` in the first quarter for returning customers becomes `60`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT qtr, cust_type, cust_cnt   
FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT qtr, 'total_cust' AS cust_type, SUM(cust_cnt) AS cust_cnt
FROM tab
GROUP BY qtr
ORDER BY qtr, cust_cnt;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the logical structure I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same when visualize the data in Tableau. It supports total if you present data in a grid but sometimes we need show the total in a dropdown list.
Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't support cube or rollup. I did use the same way what Lukasz suggested.

Comment: Definitely some things to have to get used to based on the database to visualization combo!